# How can I put textcolr and change size in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How can I put textcolr and change size in spinner

Answer (score 0):

No of course you can change it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="50dip">
   <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:id="@+id/imageNameSpinner" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textColor="@color/black_color" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_width="90dip" android:layout_height="50dip"></TextView>
      <ImageView android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/imageIconSpinner" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageNameSpinner" android:layout_height="50dip" android:layout_width="50dip"></ImageView>
   </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is a xml for custom spinner.It also shows how an imageview can be included in the spinner.

Use this as follows while defining your adapter:

```
adapterForImageSpinner = new SimpleAdapter(this, true,
            spinnerData, R.layout.spinner_view, new String[] { "Name",
                    "Icon" }, new int[] { R.id.imageNameSpinner,
                    R.id.imageIconSpinner });
```